# How should I separate this data in my database design

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I'm being  a bit confused about a database design I'm working on. It's a real estate database.

I'm trying to store the transaction mode of a property (rent or sale). I made a lookup table  called transactions so I can use Foreign keys. However each mode has additional information. Sales have the price, but rentals have the rate(ie month or semester), the price, down payment and deposit. I couldn't put them in the lookup table because there will be to much null values. So I thought of making a sales table and a rentals table both with the property id. It's a one to one relationship (one property has one transaction mode only). However I wonder if I should have the rentals id and sales id in the property table, considering the fact that one these two field might be null like this:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/127NhhhofVMzc3oyPBzHbS-5mPY2QUhEI/view?usp=sharing

or should I not put the ids in the property tab  since the rentals and sales tables already have the properties id

https://drive.google.com/file/d/13CDVpQXrleNnmEUJniC8Q9ygEi-vvjvS/view?usp=sharing

Thanks for your attention

Answer (score 0):

Put the foreign key in the sales/rental tables. After all, in theory, you might be renting a property that you also want to sell.
So: Rates.property and Sale.property both point to the Property table. You can then bring in the details with Property left join Rates on Property.id = Rates.property where Rates.property is not null.

Comment: Wait, by rates did you mean rentals. Because I'm talking about the Rentals* and Sales* table. because I'm a bit confused

Comment: Yes,rental rates.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you rent a property more than once?

To get the proper 1:many relationship, `Rentals` needs a column `property_id`, *not* the other way.  (That is option 2, not option 1)

I don't understand what a "transaction" is; I don't see any other columns that would give clues.

Comment: Indeed option 2 is what I thought. Transaction is a looku table with “rent” and “sale” as options. It’s not possible to rent or sell the same property more than once.

Comment: @Al.Salvador - I can't rent a property for a week, then someone else rents it for the next week?